# How to generate Maya 3D animation model to .h file for augmented reality vuforia?

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, vuforia

Currently, I am working on augmented reality and I am unsure about how to get the .h file from Maya for my 3D model to implement into my xcode project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Manage to use terminal to generate it with the help of obj2opengl script.
http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Comment: Thanks! That might be helpful for me in the future. Also, can you write an answer for your own question then please and mark it as answered so that this question can be complete.